# WSO2-IS 5.11.0 - System application update is not allowed

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I'm trying to update the new Console application to access in different port but I'm facing an error when I try to update:

**Callback Url** - **From** https://localhost:9443/console/login **to** https://localhost:9444/console/login

```
[2021-06-28 16:22:14,946] [dfb3d753-6fa6-47dc-99da-ff8829cde374] ERROR {org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver} - System application update is not allowed. Client id: CONSOLE java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ...
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.IdentityOAuthClientException: System application update is not allowed. Client id: CONSOLE
    at org.wso2.identity.apps.common.listner.AppPortalOAuthAppMgtListener.doPreUpdateConsumerApplication(AppPortalOAuthAppMgtListener.java:67)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.OAuthAdminServiceImpl.updateConsumerApplication(OAuthAdminServiceImpl.java:394)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.OAuthAdminService.updateConsumerApplication(OAuthAdminService.java:148)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, Myaccount and Console are read-only system apps. Remove Console from read-only system apps by adding the following to the `deployment.toml` at `<wso2is-home>/repository/conf/deployment.toml` location. (This config makes that only My Account is read-only)

```
[system_applications]
read_only_apps = ["My Account"]
```

If you want to remove both Myaccount and Console apps out of the readonly apps (allow to modify the app configs), use the following config.

```
 [system_applications]
 read_only_apps = []
```

Then restart the server. You will be able to do configuration changes now. Refer: https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.11.0/setup/migrating-what-has-changed/#configurable-system-apps

Comment: How can I change the values on Inbound Authentication Configuration - OAuth2/OpenID Connect Configuration under Identity Providers - Resident? The properties are read-only.

Comment: `[server]
offset = "1"` define offset under [server] tag in the deployment.toml file and restart the server.